# Can I have two modifiers in the same request parameter?

Tags: hl7-fhir

We are trying to create a @Search method in a FHIR Server to look for all the observations from a Patient. I have seen that the parameter can be `subject` or `patient`. We want that you could look for a Patient by Identifier, so the request should be something like this:

`GET [base]/Observation?subject:identifier=http://acme.org/fhir/identifier/mrn|123456`

or

`GET [base]/Observation?patient:identifier=http://acme.org/fhir/identifier/mrn|123456`

Our problem is that we only have Patient Identifiers with type. In order to look for a Patient by Identifier with type, you have to add the modifier :of-type. My question is, is correct to have a request with two modifiers? Just like the example below

`GET [base]/Observation?patient:identifier:of-type=http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203|MR|446053`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifiers modify the default search behaviour, not the filter that you want to put on the resource type. You can only use modifier specified by FHIR. They are listed on this page: http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html.

Your first two searches above are not valid. In order to search Observations based on a patient's identifier, you would have to do a [chained search](http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#chaining):

`GET [base]/Observation?patient.identifier=http://acme.org/fhir/identifier/mrn|123456`

This is a shortcut for 'subject' with a resource type modifier:

`GET [base]/Observation?subject:Patient.identifier=http://acme.org/fhir/identifier/mrn|123456`

If you need to incorporate the 'of-type' modifier, the search could look like this:

`GET [base]/Observation?patient.identifier:of-type=[codesystem_for_type]|MR|123456`

I prefer to use the 'patient' parameter whenever applicable, but it would also be valid to do `subject:Patient.identifier:oftype`. Edit to add: for now it is valid, but see Lloyd's answer for future FHIR versions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://jira.hl7.org/browse/FHIR-20641, the intention is to clarify that multiple modifiers are prohibited and that if you have that requirement, you need to define your own search parameter that doesn't require modifiers.  Note that this decision has not yet passed ballot.  In R4, there is no documented expectation for support, but there's no prohibition either.  In practice, we're not aware of any standard servers that provide support and, given the planned prohibition in R5, it's unlikely such support will be built.

Comment: I agree with the point made in the ticket about stacking modifiers, but the search in the question was actually incorrect and needs a chain instead of stacked modifiers.

Comment: @MirjamBaltus - thanks for reading more closely than I did :)